Flutter ios location fetching not working at start of application
I am building an application for prayer timings to fetch current location prayer. its working fine on android emulator but for ios device as well as ios emulator its not working. Its taking to siri, search page for getting loication access but nothing there to select/enable location for my app then app is throwing out error, null check operator used on null value
I have location.dart file as given below
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class AppLocation {
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  String? cityName;
  String? countryName;

  // Function to get the current location
  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      // Check if permission is already granted
      bool isPermissionGranted = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.isGranted;

      // Request location permission if not already granted
      if (!isPermissionGranted) {
        PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.locationWhenInUse.request();
        isPermissionGranted = permission.isGranted;
      }

      if (isPermissionGranted) {
        // Fetch the current location if permission is granted
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
            desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

        latitude = position.latitude;
        longitude = position.longitude;

        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
          await getCityAndCountryName(latitude!, longitude!);
        } else {
          print('Error: Latitude or Longitude is null.');
        }
      } else if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.isDenied) {
        print('Location permission denied.');
        await openAppSettings(); // Optionally prompt the user to enable permissions in settings
      } else if (await Permission.locationWhenInUse.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        print('Location permission permanently denied.');
        await openAppSettings(); // Direct user to app settings
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error occurred while fetching location: $e');
    }
  }

  // Function to get the city and country name based on coordinates
  Future<void> getCityAndCountryName(double latitude, double longitude) async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
      if (placemarks.isNotEmpty) {
        cityName = placemarks.first.locality ?? 'Unknown City';
        countryName = placemarks.first.country ?? 'Unknown Country';
      } else {
        print('No placemarks found');
        cityName = 'Unknown';
        countryName = 'Unknown';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error occurred while fetching city and country name: $e');
      cityName = 'Unknown';
      countryName = 'Unknown';
    }
  }

  // Function to get coordinates from a city name
  Future<Map<String, double>> getCoordinatesFromCity(String cityName) async {
    try {
      List<Location> locations = await locationFromAddress(cityName);
      if (locations.isNotEmpty) {
        return {
          'latitude': locations.first.latitude,
          'longitude': locations.first.longitude,
        };
      } else {
        throw Exception('No locations found for the provided city name');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error occurred while fetching coordinates: $e');
    }
  }
}

Podfile
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # You can remove unused permissions here
      # for more information: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',  # Enable location permission

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
      ]
    end
  end
end

Info.Plist File

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <!-- Permission options for the `location` group -->
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need location when in use</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always and when in use!</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Older devices need location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can I have location always?</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Namazpro</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>namazpro</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

